# How to animate an image from one container to another in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

In Flutter, I want to move an image in a container into another container positioned another part of the screen with animation.

Which animation packages do I need to use to do this? Can you help me?

Best wishes...

[image: Click for image.]

When I click on one of the playing cards in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EtcF.png), I want the card to be moved into the container in the center.

Comment: Can you refer any visual look and your current code

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I added an image.

Answer (score 0):

Use [flutter_draggable_gridview: ^0.0.7](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_draggable_gridview)

```
DraggableGridViewBuilder(
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3),
    ),
    children: _listOfDraggableGridItem,
    isOnlyLongPress: false,
    dragCompletion: (List<DraggableGridItem> list, int beforeIndex, int afterIndex) {
      print( 'onDragAccept: $beforeIndex -> $afterIndex');
    },
    dragFeedback: (List<DraggableGridItem> list, int index) {
      return Container(
        child: list[index].child,
        width: 200,
        height: 150,
      );
    },
    dragPlaceHolder: (List<DraggableGridItem> list, int index) {
     return PlaceHolderWidget(
        child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  },
  );
```